# How can I filter results of REST API SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getUpgradeItemPrices?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to filter the result of getUpgradeItemPrices using this URL:

```
https://<user>:<password>@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/<vsi-id>/getUpgradeItemPrices.json?objectFilter={"upgradeItemPrices":{"id":{"operation":273}}}
```

However, the filter is not applying and all upgrade item prices are returned. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getUpgradeItemPrices does not support object filters.

For more information see in the following link, the "Optional Headers" option:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getUpgradeItemPrices/